# How would the if/else-if statement handle this?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I was just wondering about something that popped into my mind while writing some code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_bits; i++) {
       if (bits.at(i) == 0) {

       }

    else if (bits.at(i) == 1) {

    }
}
```

In this code, `bits` is a string and `num_bits` is the length of the string.

In this case, would the program run `string.at(i)` at both the `if` and the `else if``, or would it run it once and then store it somewhere and use it at both of the statements? I don't know if the question was clear enough, but thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it. How would the engine know that every call to that function would produce the same result?

Comment: Thanks, that was my initial thought. Do you think it would be more efficient to turn the string to a char array or vector or something like that, instead of calling the function all the time?

Comment: Start with storing the value to a variable and compare with the variable and you only need to call the method once. Or you could use bits[i]

Comment: g++ on -O1 or higher is smart enough to create that temporary for you.  Notice that the assembly is the same [with](https://godbolt.org/g/XVleS5) and [without](https://godbolt.org/g/ecH5gI) an explicit temporary.

Comment: I must admit that I was answering for JavaScript. Didn't see the hints that it was not. A compiler could of course do all kinds of smart things. Makes the question more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It wil run the function whenever you call it, so for this example 2 times. You can declare it at the top of the for loop or use a foreach if you need to do more heavy operations.